# How to create a window that opens another window with uic module ?? Qt-Designer and Python

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer, uic

I have a problem when trying to develop a GUI with PyQt5 and QT designer.

I want to use the `uic` module, I have a `.ui` file called `registro.ui`, and another `login.ui`, as I can call from `login.ui` to the `registry.ui`,by clicking on buttom `registro`

I also have the `Login.py` , `Registro.py`  files respectively

My intention is to click the register button, and open the registration window

Using only the `uic.loadUI()` method?

Here I show my code

**Class Login**
`login.py`

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import Con_pos
from Registro import Registro
class Login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Login.ui", self)
        self.registro.clicked.connect(self.view_Registro)
        self.ingresar.clicked.connect(self.autenticar)

    def autenticar(self):
        pid = self.getPID()
        con = Con_pos.con_pos()
        user = self.in_login.text()
        password = self.in_pass.text()
        print(password)
        fecha = time.strftime("%X") + " " + time.strftime("%x")
        if user != "" and password != "":
            consulta = ''' SELECT "id_user" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s' ; ''' %(user)
            c_user = con.consulta(consulta)
            print(c_user)
            consulta = ''' SELECT "pass" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s' ;''' %(user)
            c_pass = con.consulta(consulta)
            if c_user != None:
                c_pass = c_pass[0]
                print("test")
                print(c_pass)
                if c_pass == password:
                    consulta = ''' INSERT INTO "sesion" VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s'); '''%(fecha ,pid, user)
                    con.insertar(consulta)
    def getPID(self):
        con = Con_pos.con_pos()
        func = "pg_backend_pid"
        pid = con.call_proc(func)
        pid = pid[0][0]
        return pid

    def view_Registro(self):
        reg = Registro.Registro()
        reg.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Class Registro:**
`Registro.py`

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
import Con_pos
import error_log as error

class Registro(QMainWindow):
    con = Con_pos.con_pos()
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Registro.ui", self)
        self.btn_reg.clicked.connect(self.validar_nombre)

    def validar_nombre(self):
        fecha = time.strftime("%X") + " " + time.strftime("%x")
        usuario = self.user_tx_input.text()
        password = self.pass_tx_input.text()
        if usuario != "":
            pid = self.getPID()
            consul = '''SELECT "id_user" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s'; ''' % (usuario)
            res_con = Registro.con.consulta(consul)

            if not res_con:
                ins_user = '''INSERT INTO "User" VALUES ('%s', '%s') ''' % (usuario, password)
                ins_sesion = ''' INSERT INTO "sesion" VALUES ('%s', %s,'%s') ''' % (fecha, pid, usuario)
                Registro.con.insertar(ins_user)
                Registro.con.insertar(ins_sesion)
            else:
                err = error.error_dia()
                err.etiqueta.setText("El usuario %s ya esta en uso" % (usuario))
                err.exec()

    def getPID(self):
        func = "pg_backend_pid"
        pid = Registro.con.call_proc(func)
        pid = pid[0][0]
        return pid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Registro()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: When you call the Registration window, what happens to the login window is kept open or closed?

Comment: The problem is that I can not call the "Registro" window, I get an error, and it closes everything, but my goal is to open the "Registro" window through the login

Comment: I have proposed a solution, please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass as a parent a parameter to the new window, you can do it in two ways:

1. *first solution:* Make the variable reg an attribute of the class:

---

```
def view_Registro(self):
    self.reg = Registro()
    self.reg.show()
```

2. *Second Solution:* Pass as a parameter to the same instance:

---

```
def view_Registro(self):
    reg = Registro(self)
    reg.show()
```

For this solution you must change:

```
class Registro(QMainWindow):
    con = Con_pos.con_pos()
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
```

to

```
class Registro(QMainWindow):
    con = Con_pos.con_pos()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
```

Comment: Hello already try, the 2 steps you gave me but I still leave error

The error that I get is the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Login.py", line 43, in view_Registro
     Reg = Record.Registration (self)
AttributeError: type object 'Record' has no attribute 'Record'
[1] 434 abort (core dumped) python Login.py

Comment: Use the first solution

Comment: Are 2 solutions, not 2 steps.

Comment: Sorry no quize say step, well probe the 2 solutions but if I give myself error:
AttributeError: type object 'Registro' has no attribute 'Registro'.
It should be noted that the log window is QMainWindow and login is Widget
I use python3

Comment: You speak Spanish?

Comment: Just try the first solution